# How can I assign "metadata" to a trait?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have 2 macros. The first is `special_trait`, an attribute macro to be used on trait declarations, and the second, `useful_macro` is used with such traits.

That is, the user code would write:

```rust
#[special_trait]
pub trait MyTrait{}

// meanwhile, in a different file...

use some_mod::MyTrait;

useful_macro!(MyTrait);
```

Now, the `special_trait` macro needs to assign some metadata to `MyTrait` in a way that `useful_macro` can use it.

Is this possible and how?

### Possible but sub-optimal solution

It occurred to me that I could require all user code to specify the full path to the trait, instead of relying on `use`:

```rust
#[special_trait]
pub trait MyTrait{}

// meanwhile, in a different file...

useful_macro!(some_mod::MyTrait);
```

Then, `special_trait` merely needs to define a `pub const MyTrait_METADATA: i32 = 42`, and `useful_macro` can find the path to this metadata const since it has the full `some_mod::MyTrait` path, and only the last segment needs to be changed: `some_mod::MyTrait_METADATA`.

However, forbidding `use` and requiring the full path seems mean, and I don't want to do that if there is a better way.

Can I associate a metadata const with a trait in a way that any macro having "access" to the trait also can find the metadata?

Comment: I am quite inexperienced with Rust macros, but maybe you can use [the `$crate` metavariable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#hygiene) to resolve this `MyTrait_METADATA` without needing a full path?

Comment: @Thomas hmm, looks like `$crate` refers to the macro's crate, yet I would need the crate where the trait is defined, which would be different. Thanks though! I'm new to macros too.

Comment: Why can't you use associated constants on your trait?

Comment: Ah, right, but then the code without `$crate` would find the right things in scope, wouldn't it?

Comment: @IvanC, I need to access the metadata even when I don't have access to an implementation of the trait. If I understand correctly, the associated constants don't really exist on the trait, but only the structs that implement it. I tried that and I kept getting "could not determine type" or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rocket v4 has the same problem:

> When a route is declared inside a module other than the root, you may find yourself with unexpected errors when mounting:
>
> ```rust
> mod other {
>     #[get("/world")]
>     pub fn world() -> &'static str {
>         "Hello, world!"
>     }
> }
>
> #[get("/hello")]
> pub fn hello() -> &'static str {
>     "Hello, outside world!"
> }
>
> use other::world;
>
> fn main() {
>     // error[E0425]: cannot find value `static_rocket_route_info_for_world` > in this scope
>     rocket::ignite().mount("/hello", routes![hello, world]);
> }
> ```
>
> This occurs because the routes! macro implicitly converts the route's name into the name of a structure generated by Rocket's code generation. The solution is to refer to the route using a namespaced path instead:
>
> ```rust
> rocket::ignite().mount("/hello", routes![hello, other::world]);
> ```

In Rocket v5 (currently, there's only a release candidate), this does not happen anymore. For example, this compiles with Rocket v5:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

mod module {
    #[get("/bar")]
    pub fn route() -> &'static str {
        "Hello, world!"
    }
}

use module::route;

fn main() {
    rocket::build().mount("/foo", routes![route]);
}
```

When running [`cargo-expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) on this, we see that Rocket generates something like this (abbreviated by me):

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
mod module {
    pub fn route() -> &'static str {
        "Hello, world!"
    }
    #[doc(hidden)]
    #[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
    /// Rocket code generated proxy structure.
    pub struct route {}
    /// Rocket code generated proxy static conversion implementations.
    impl route {
        #[allow(non_snake_case, unreachable_patterns, unreachable_code)]
        fn into_info(self) -> ::rocket::route::StaticInfo {
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
```

The `get` attribute macro that is applied to a function constructs a new struct with the same name as the function. That struct contains the metadata (or, more correctly, contains a function `into_info()` that returns a struct with the correct metadata – though this is more of an detail of the implementation used by Rocket).

This works because [function declarations live in the Value Namespace while struct declarations live in the Type Namespace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/names/namespaces.html). The `use` declaration [imports both](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/names/namespaces.html#use-declarations).

---

Let's apply this to your example: Your trait declaration lives in the Type Namespace, just like structs. So, while you can't have your `special_trait` macro declare a struct of the same name the trait has, you *could* have that macro declare a *function* of the same name that returns a struct containing the metadata. This function can then be invoked by `useful_macro!` to access the metadata of the trait. So, for example, the metadata struct could look like this:

```rust
struct TraitMetadata {
    name: String
}
```

Your macros could then expand something like this:

```rust
mod other {
    #[special_trait]
    pub trait MyTrait{}
}

use some_mod::MyTrait;
fn main() {
    useful_macro!(MyTrait);
}
```

to this:

```rust
mod other {
    pub trait MyTrait{}
    
    pub fn MyTrait() -> TraitMetadata {
        TraitMetadata {
            name: "MyTrait".to_string()
        }
    }
}

use other::MyTrait;
fn main() {
    do_something_with_trait_metadata(MyTrait());
}
```

---

This design has only one problem: If the user declares a function (or anything else living in the Value Namespace) that has the same name as the trait, this fails. However:

1. In idiomatic Rust, functions names are `snake_case` while trait names are `CamelCase`, so if the user uses idiomatic identifiers, he won't ever have a function with the same name that the trait uses.
2. Even if the user uses non-idiomatic names, using the same identifier for a trait and a function is just asking for trouble. I doubt that anyone (well, anyone except macro authors) would ever do this.

So, the only realistic way this may lead to conflicts is that another macro author is also using this construct to attach metadata to traits, and the user applies your attribute macro **and** the other macro **on the same trait**. In my opinion, this is an edge case that will happen so infrequently that it is not worth supporting.

Comment: Woah. So types and values can have the same name without a conflict. And importing that name imports both... this is the first truly surprising thing I've learned about Rust.

But it looks like it solves my problem perfectly! It does feel slightly hacky, but then I'm writing some very unorthodox macros, so that's expected. Will try it out, thanks!

Comment: Also, thank you for such an amazingly detailed answer for my slightly weird question!

Comment: You're welcome! I agree, while macros in Rust are in most instances less hacky than their C counterpart, they still have room for improvements in regards to readability IMO. It feels especially hacky that to attach metadata to traits, you use a function, but to attach metadata to functions you use a struct (and probably use even more constructs to attach metadata to other stuff) – there's just is no general rule/easy pattern to follow.